# Try/Catch not catching execption

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have this piece of code

```
 Me.WebDetailsByIDTableAdapter.FillbyID(Me.WebDataSet.WebDetailsByID, CType(Me.WebRefSpinEdit.Text, Integer))
```

within a Try / Catch Block.

The TableAdapter is filled from an internet database. Our service provider has us behind a dynamic IP address. So periodically we have to log into the database control panel to allow access from our IP.

When I run the code in debug mode I receive the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Authentication to host '####' for user '###' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user '#' to database '###'

The try catch block is:

```
  Private Sub frmCourse_Details_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.WebConString)
    Try
        Me.BodiesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MainDataSet.Bodies)
        Me.ListCompaniesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MainDataSet.ListCompanies)
        Me.StatusTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MainDataSet.Status)
        Me.CourseLIstTableAdapter.FillCoursesList(Me.MainDataSet.CourseLIst)
        Me.CourseDocumentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MainDataSet.CourseDocuments, Me.CourseTextEdit.GetColumnValue("ID"))

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.DateofCourseDateEdit1.Text) Then
            Me.barFolderStatus.Caption = "Folder Not FOUND"
        Else
            Dim d As Date = Me.DateofCourseDateEdit1.Text

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(GetCourseDirectory(CSEID))
            If System.IO.Directory.Exists(GetCourseDirectory(CSEID)) Then
                Me.barFolderStatus.Caption = GetCourseDirectory(CSEID) & " - Folder OK!"

            Else
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(GetCourseDirectory(CSEID))
                Me.barFolderStatus.Caption = "Folder Not FOUND"
            End If
        End If
        Me.RolesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MainDataSet.Roles)

        Me.InstructorsByCourseTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MainDataSet.InstructorsByCourse, Me.CourseTextEdit.Text)

        If Me.CourseTypeTextEdit.Text = "Internal" And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.WebRefSpinEdit.Text) Then
            Me.WebDetailsByIDTableAdapter.FillbyID(Me.WebDataSet.WebDetailsByID, CType(Me.WebRefSpinEdit.Text, Integer))
        End If

        Me.InstsGrid.RefreshData()

        con.Open()

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            BarStaticItem1.Caption = "Website Access OK"
        Else
            BarStaticItem1.Caption = "No Website Access"
        End If

        InitialSetDetails()

        UpdateRibbon()

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("Load Course Details:" & ex.Message)

    Finally
        con.Dispose()

    End Try

    Me.IDSpinEdit.ReadOnly = True
End Sub
```

Why is this exception not being caught? Is there some other error handling code I should be implementing?

Comment: Your `Try` block is empty in the example given. Please post the full, relevant code

Comment: @DaveB When you say "run the code in debug mode" do you mean "run the code using Visual Studio"? If so, this is expected behaviour - Visual Studio will, by default, show you the exception before it is passed onto the exception handler. You can modify this behaviour by going to "Debug" -> "Windows" -> "Exception Settings" and clearing the tickboxes for the relevant exceptions under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Alternatively, just continue the program, and the exception will be passed onto the exception handler.

Comment: @RB. Thanks! Yes in Visual Studio. That's solved it. I thought it wasn't being caught at all.